# IPN "Expired". Registered a Void notification

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, authorize.net

I am not sure what should I have done to not get in this situation. 
Comments history:

```
Jul 11, 2014 10:06:27 AM|Processing
Customer Notification Not Applicable
Authorized amount of $50.24. Transaction ID: "xxxx".
```

```
Aug 10, 2014 2:06:45 PM|Processing
Customer Notification Not Applicable
IPN "Expired". Registered a Void notification. Amount: $50.24. Transaction ID: "xxxx-void".
```

---

I know that 30 days passed and that's why expired. I don't understand why the money weren't taken. Are they taken only when a shipment and then the invoice are created?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found my answer: I have set Authorization and in order to take money I should have logged in Paypal to approve the transaction. I will just change to Sale and from now on I hope there won't be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Authorize payment action in most cases. Payment action Sale can be used only if you immidiatly ship goods to the customer which i suppose is not you case. See more details here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRelatedAPIOps/

Comment: This is the way the client wants. The orders are sent to fulfillment company and they will deliver the goods.

Comment: If my answer resolved the problem i would appreciate to have it marked as an answer to your question.